# Nested React-Hook-Form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx, react-hook-form, yup

Is it possible to have a nested form inside a larger form using [React-Hook-Form](https://react-hook-form.com/)?

I have a larger form component that I want a button to cause a [MUI Dialog](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/) component to display with a mini-form inside it that will have its own validators. When data is successfully added on the dialog form it should add that data to the table.

Table details aren't important here, what I need to know is if the nested/internal form is possible. I've seen posts about two forms in a component like `<form/><form/>` but none about `yup` validation in nested forms like `<form><form></form></form>`.

Roughly it would look like below.

```
<Box component="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleOnSubmit)}>
    //Parent form fields here

    <Table/>
    //button and dialog are in a separate .jsx component 
    //but left here for demonstration purposes
    <button onClick={openDialog}>Add</button>
    <Dialog
        fullScreen={fullScreen}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="responsive-dialog-title"
      >
        <Box component="form"
             onSubmit={handleSubmit2(handleOnSubmit2)}>
            <DialogTitle id="responsive-dialog-title">
              Fill out fields
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
                <FormControl fullWidth size="small">
                <Controller
                  control={control2}
                  name="identifier"
                  render={({ field, formState }) => (
                    <>
                      <TextField
                        {...field}
                        size="small"
                        autoFocus
                        id="identifier"
                        label="Identifier"
                        fullWidth
                      />
                      <FormHelperText error>{" "}</FormHelperText>
                    </>
                  )}
                />
              </FormControl>
               //other fields
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
              <Button autoFocus onClick={handleClose}>
                Disagree
              </Button>
              <Button variant="contained" type="submit" autoFocus>
                Save
              </Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Box>
      </Dialog>
</Box>
```

I've tried using separate `useForm` on each but it looks like validation is still connected with each other. So the parent form gets validated and blocks submit of the child form if it fails.

Would it be better to not use React-Hook-Form for the internal form? I thought about the `useFieldArray` but it doesn't seem like the appropriate use in this case as I want separate validation and not be able to change the fields after submitting the inner form.

Is this even possible and if so, is it not-recommended?